# Characterisation of (integrable) connections on (trivial) principal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $M$ be a manifold. Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra.

Let $P(M,G)$ be a principal bundle. Recall that, a connection on $P(M,G)$ is a distribution $\mathcal{H}\subseteq TP$ satisfying certain conditions. Equivalently, a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued differential forms on $P$ satisfying certain conditions.

Question : Is there a characterization of connections on $P(M,G)$; in the sense, a one-one correspondence between the set of connections on $P(M,G)$ and some "well-described set"?

Question : Can we say something if we restrict to the case of integrable connections?

Questions : Can we say something when the bundle is trivial bundle? A characterization for integrable connections on trivial principal bundle?

Edit : May be it is already clear but, I want to specify that I am seeing two connections $\omega, \omega’$ to be same if there exists an isomorphism $\varphi :P\rightarrow P’$ Of vector bundles such that $\varphi^*\omega’=\omega$, that is the pullback of $\omega’$ is equal to $\omega$.

Comment: Consider the trivial bundle $pr_1:M\times G\rightarrow M$. See that, for each $(m,g)\in M\times G$, the kernel of $(pr_1)_{*,(m,g)}=T_gG$. The assignment $(m,g)\mapsto T_mM$ then defines a connectionon on the bundle $M\times G\rightarrow M$. This is an integrable connection...

Comment: Connections are affine over $\Omega^1(M;\mathfrak g)$, and in particular form an affine space. Integrable connections are the same thing as flat conns, which are the zeroes of the curvature map $F_A$. Such a map gives rise to a holonomy map $\pi_1 M \to G$. The space of all flat connections on $P$ carries the action of the automorphism group of $P$, and the space of homomorphisms to $G$, the action of conjugation. After quotienting this descends to a bijection from the space of flat conns to the subset of $\text{Hom}(\pi_1 M, G)$ so that $\tilde M \times_{\pi_1 M} G \cong P$ as G-bundles.

Comment: If your question is how to tell what the topological type of the bundle $\tilde M \times_{\pi_1 M} G$ is given the homomorphism $\rho: \pi_1 M \to G$, you will probably first want to know how to determine the isomorphism classes of principal G-bundles over M, and then to determine it by hand for your representation $\rho$... in particular it's not hard if $G = U(1)$!

Comment: What is $\tilde{M}$ here? Is it the universal cover of $M$? @MikeMiller Can you suggest some reference for “After quotienting this descends to a bijection from the space of flat conns to the subset of $Hom(\pi_1 M,G)$”

Comment: @MikeMiller any reference regarding your second comment would be useful.

Comment: Yes, universal cover. The stuff in the first comment is in most references on connections; I am surprised to not see it in Kobayashi-Nomizu vol 1, but see eg Taubes, "Differential geometry: [...]", Theorem 13.2 (here he does not separate the set of flat connections by the topological type of the bundle, but rather just lists off all flat connections on all principal bundles). I am not sure what it would mean to give a reference for my second comment, unless you mean the comment about $U(1)$, in which case try playing with UCT and the LES in homology coming from SES of the coefficient groups.

Comment: @MikeMiller I have checked Kobayashi before asking you.. It was not there.. So, I had to bother you... I see the theorem.... I will read that... Frankly, I do not completely understand the second comment.. I will come back to second comment after reading that theorem 13.2.. Thanks for the reference...

Comment: Atleast for trivial Principal $G$ bundles a partial answer to your question is mentioned in the Theorem 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.4485.pdf. Also for non trivial Principal $G$ bundles a partial answer can be found in the section "Idea" in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/connection+on+a+bundle where you may find a one-one correspondence(not sure about 1 direction) between connections on Principal $G$ bundles over $M$ and an appropriate subset of functors from Path groupoid of $M$ to the  Atiyah Lie Groupoid of the principal $G$ bundle.

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri +1 for Theorem $1$ that gives a one-one correspondence between $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-forms on $M$ and the set of connections on the trivial principal bundle $M\times G\rightarrow M$... I do not understand the other half of the theorem that says there is a one one correspondence between the above mentioned set and the set of "smooth" functors $\mathcal{P}_1(M)\rightarrow G$.. I never understood what is smooth structure on $\mathcal{P}_1(M)$.. Do you want to shre your thoughts on smoothness of these functors?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Sure! Please checkout this link https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smooth+structure+of+the+path+groupoid

Comment: @AdittyaChaudhuri I mean to share your understanding of smooth structure, not the link :P I have seen that before... Did not understand much...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik In Generalised smooth space (like diffeologocal space, Chen space..etc)  quotient always exist which fails in smooth manifolds. (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.1704.pdf)Though Path groupoid in general do not have standard manifold structure but  can be considered as generalised space (According to https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1970846.pdf?seq=1 set of piecewise differentiable paths has a Chen space structure.Now underlying set of Path groupoid is the quotient of set of path(here thin homotopy) ... hence quotient is also Chen space which is an example of gen smooth space.)

Comment: :) See if you can make it as an answer by adding as many details as you can..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Path groupoid can also be treated as a diffeological space (see the definition of path groupoid here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+groupoid)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik To make it an answer my explanation should be complete. For example I did not talk about "integrable connections" at all(I do not have much idea about those right now.). So it's better if an expert(which I am definitely not) answer your question with full details so that we both can learn from it :).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Can you please define what do you mean by an integrable connection on a principal $G$ bundle?

Comment: A distribution $\mathcal{H}\subseteq TP$ on a manifold $P$ is said to be an integrable distriibution if, for any two vector fields $X,Y:P\rightarrow TP$ that lies in $\mathcal{H}$, in the sense $X(p),y(p)\in \mathcal{H}_pP$ for each $p\in P$, then, the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ lies in $\mathcal{H}$, in the above sense.. A connection on a principal bundle is given in terms of distribution.. If it is integrable, we call it integrable connection

Comment: In this site, at least for my questions, partial answers are welcome... You can add what ever you know.. Not a problem at all..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Thanks for the notion of integrable connection. Ok I will try to give the answer :).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik on the trivial principal bundle, a $\mathfrak g$-valued form $\omega$ corresponds to an integrable connection if and only if $\omega$ satisfies the Maurer-Cartan equation $d\omega + \frac{1}{2} [\omega,\omega] = 0$.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - you find a similar question (and answers) here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123942/how-many-flat-connections-has-a-line-bundle-in-algebraic-geometry/393770#393770

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. This is in response to Mike Miller's comment.

Let $M$ be a manifold, $\tilde{M}$ to be its associated universal cover (a simply connected covering space over $M$). I do not understand why they are not assuming $M$ to be connected. I am assuming $M$ is a connected manifold.

The following result is from the book Differential Geometry - Bundles, Connections, Metrics and Curvature by Clifford Henry Taubes.

Theorem $13.2$ (classification theorem for flat connections) says that, there is a bijection between the sets $\mathcal{F}_{M,G}$ and the set $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)/G$ where,

1. $\mathcal{F}_{M,G}$ denote the set of equivalence classes of pairs $(P,A)$, where  $P\rightarrow M$ is a principal $G$ bundle, and $A$ is a flat connection on $P(M,G)$. Two pairs $(P,A)$ and $(P',A')$ are equivalent, if there is an isomorphism of principal $G$-bundles $(\varphi,1_M):(P,M)\rightarrow (P',M)$ such that $\varphi^*A'=A$ (pullback of connection $A'$ is the connection $A$).
2. $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)/G$ denote the set of equivalence classes of group homomorphisms $\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$. Two morphisms $f_1:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$ and $f_2:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$ are equivalent if there exists $g\in G$ such that $f_1=gf_2g^{-1}:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$.

The bijection $\mathcal{F}_{M,G}\rightarrow \text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)/G$ is given as follows:

- given a principal bundle $P(M,G)$ with flat connection $A$, we get a group homomorphism $\pi(M)\rightarrow G$. Its equivalence class gives an element in $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)/G$.
- Let $\rho:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$ be a representative of an element in $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M),G)/G$. Consider the trivial principal $G$-bundle $\tilde{M}\times G\rightarrow \tilde{M}$. The map $\rho:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$ given an action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $G$, which in turn gives an action of $\pi_1(M)$ on $\tilde{M}\times G$. Thus, trivial principal bundle $\tilde{M}\times G\rightarrow \tilde{M}$ induce 
  $(\tilde{M}\times G)/\pi_1(M)\rightarrow M$. Thus, we get a principal $G$-bundle  over $M$, which we denote by $\tilde{M}\times_{\rho}G\rightarrow M$. It turns out that, there exists a $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-form on $\tilde{M}\times_{\rho}G\rightarrow M$ whose pullback to $\tilde{M}\times G\rightarrow \tilde{M}$ is the canonical connection on the trivial bundle. It turns out that this $\mathfrak{g}$-valued $1$-form on $\tilde{M}\times_{\rho}G\rightarrow M$ is a flat connection on the principal bundle $\tilde{M}\times_{\rho}G\rightarrow M$. Thus, we get a principal bundle $(P_\rho,A_{\rho})$. Take its equivalence class to get an element in $\mathcal{F}_{M,G}$.

It is not clear how does this answer the question:

> Given a principal bundle $P\rightarrow M$, how does one know for what
>   $\rho:\pi_1(M)\rightarrow G$, do we get that that there is an
>   isomorphism of principal bundle $P\cong \tilde{M}\times_{\rho}G$?

I am also interested in only "different" connections in the sense if two connections on $(P,M)$ are related by an isomorphism, in the sense of pullbacks, then I am calling these to be same.

Comment: If anyone wants to see more details, who do not have the book, I can give more details...

Comment: It sounds like the missing piece for you is this image. As I said in my comment: $\rho$ is in the image of $\mathcal F_P$ iff the $G$-bundle $(\widetilde M \times_\rho G))$ is isomorphic to $P$ as a G-bundle, where the subscript $\rho$ indicates we identify $(x, g) \sim (\gamma x, \rho(\gamma) g)$ for all $\gamma, x, g$, thinking of $\gamma \in \pi_1 M$ as a deck transformation. This is as explicit as you will ever get in full generality. If you have a specific bundle over a specific manifold (or your group G is not complicated) you may be able to get better answers by ad hoc techniques.

Comment: @MikeMiller I have clarified that part.. Do you have a procedure to write this down explicitly if I have a principal bundle over a manifold when the group G is reasonably good.. Any reference is welcome.. I enjoyed reading chapter 13 of Taubes book..